# Trying to parse multiple strings using strtok?

Tags: c, string, parsing, strtok

So I have an input file made of numbers characters. Such as

```
1 4 5 6 7

2 4 5 6 7

1 3
```

I am currently using strtok to parse my strings. However my code only takes in the first 2 numbers. I'm confused as to why. So for example my program reads this:

```
1 4

2 4

1 3
```

The program:

```
while(fgets(line, MAX_LEN, in)!=NULL) {
    token= strtok(line, " \n");

    while(token!=NULL){

          if(atoi(token)+1>0){
              if(count==2){
                  vertex=atoi(token);
                   printf("vertex=%d\n",vertex);
               } if(count==1){
                   queue=atoi(token);
                   count++;
                   printf("queue=%d\n", queue);
               } if(count==0){
                   printf("count=%d\n",count);
                   customer=atoi(token);
                   count++;
                   printf("custs=%d\n", customer);
               }
           token= strtok(NULL, "\n");
     }
}
```

Comment: If the number of tokens in each line is fixed...why cant you try sscanf?

Comment: @Raghuram Because... the number of tokens is **not** fixed, you just have to read the example input.

Comment: you forgot a space in the last `strtok`

Comment: Oh doh! Thanks Elazar! Can't believe I didn't catch that